# AsyncTask Error on Android 2.3.4

Tags: android, android-asynctask, runtime-error

When I run my AsyncTask class on my Samsung galaxy S3(4.1.1) it runs perfectly fine but when I run it on my HTC Android(2.3.4) I get the below error.  What is the issue here?

Here is the class.

```
    public class enemyHandler extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
    {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - lastSpawn >= 2000)
            {
                Enemy x = new Enemy(SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT, enemy.getHeight());
                enemies.add(x);

                lastSpawn = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++)
            {
                Enemy tempE = enemies.get(i);
                if(tempE.x <= 0 - enemy.getWidth())
                    enemies.remove(tempE);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Logcat output:

```
03-14 18:04:53.656: E/AndroidRuntime(4279): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-12
03-14 18:04:53.656: E/AndroidRuntime(4279): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
03-14 18:04:53.656: E/AndroidRuntime(4279):     at com.jister13.plane.Main$SView.run(Main.java:188)
03-14 18:04:53.656: E/AndroidRuntime(4279):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1027)
03-14 18:04:53.656: E/AndroidRuntime(4279): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()
03-14 18:04:53.656: E/AndroidRuntime(4279):     at android.os.Handler.<init>(Handler.java:121)
03-14 18:04:53.656: E/AndroidRuntime(4279):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:421)
03-14 18:04:53.656: E/AndroidRuntime(4279):     at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.<init>(AsyncTask.java:421)
03-14 18:04:53.656: E/AndroidRuntime(4279):     at android.os.AsyncTask.<clinit>(AsyncTask.java:152)
03-14 18:04:53.656: E/AndroidRuntime(4279):     ... 2 more
```

SOLUTION:

I was able to solve this problem by calling my

```
AsyncTask().execute("");
```

in the onCreate() so as to create the class itself and then recalling it where I wanted it to be run...

Comment: enemy is added to UI?

Answer (score 0):

Something that must get called in the UI thread is not called there.
1. You must call the `AsyncTask`'s `execute` on the UI thread.
2. Don't handle UI objects on your `AsyncTask` (views).

Please provide us with more information on the `Enemy` class (what is it exactly?) and on the code the executing the `AsyncTask`.

After providing us with the rest of your code:
As I said, you do start the `AsyncTask` from a thread that is not the UI thread.
Your `SurfaceView` implements `Runnable`, and the part that executing the `AsyncTask` is in the `Thread.run` method.
In your activity's `onCreate` you are creating the `SurfaceView` and in the `onResume` (called after `onCreate`), you are starting a new thread (t1), which executing the `AsyncTask`.
To be able to execute this `AsyncTask` properly, you need to post the code that doing it to the UI thread. `AsyncTasks` must be started from the UI thread.

Please read about the `android.os.Handler` class:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

And you can see a simple example here:
[Android: Accessing UI Element from timer thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738239/android-accessing-ui-element-from-timer-thread)

I don't know why it's working in 4.1, maybe they did some changes to cover those mistakes of executing `AsyncTasks` from the UI thread.

Comment: Currently my Async task is called from a SurfaceviewClass which is called in onCreate()

Comment: @Josh, I'm pretty sure that you start the `AsyncTask` from a thread that is not the UI thread, because you have initialization error. Please post here the code and see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4187960/asynctask-and-looper-prepare-error