# Animations and update in Android

Tags: android, multithreading, animation, timer

I'm having an issue with my Android application.

I have a button and a textView. When the button is clicked, the textview move with a translate and a rotate, then a Timer is set to change the content of the TextView each second.

The problem is that when I start the animation, and then start the timer, the view is no longer updated. Until I stop the timer! When the timer is stopped, the view take the last value affected in this timer.

Here is the code: http://pastebin.com/n1e1djdX

**EDIT:**

Solved with http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try Property Animation, it can help you. see http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/prop-animation.html

Comment: Property Animation System is usable only in application with 3.0+ Android version. Depends on which version user2447845 is using.

Comment: Thanks, it works even better and smoother with that!

Answer (score 1):

Non primary thread cannot access or modify UI Views. You must use Handlers or AsyncTask classes with onProgressChanged() method overridden.

Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738239/android-accessing-ui-element-from-timer-thread)

Comment: I used runOnUIThread, and even with handlers it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can only use Property Animation on Honeycomb and up. Try downloading NineOldAndroids library (http://nineoldandroids.com/), that way you get the Android 3.0+ animation API on all versions of the platform back to 1.0